# Ada -- Array of queues of unconstrained objects results in Storage_Error -- How to resolve?

Tags: arrays, generics, containers, ada, variant

So, disclaimer, I've only been using Ada for a few weeks now... I expect to have a noob mistake causing this.

So the (anonymized) code I have...

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

with Ada.Containers.Synchronized_Queue_Interfaces;
with Ada.Containers.Bounded_Synchronized_Queues;

procedure Hello is
  type ID_Type is ( Invalid_Id,
                    Config_Id);

  for ID_Type use ( Invalid_Id => 16#00#,
                    Config_Id => 16#11#  );
  for ID_Type'Size use 8;                  

  type Config_Type is 
    record
      data : Integer;
    end record;

  type Data_Type (i : ID_Type := Invalid_Id) is 
    record
      Id : ID_Type := i;

      case i is
        when Invalid_Id => null;
        when Config_Id => config : Config_Type;
        when others => null;
      end case; 
    end record with Unchecked_Union, Convention => C;

  package Queue_Interface is
    new Ada.Containers.Synchronized_Queue_Interfaces(Data_Type);

  package Data_Queue is 
    new Ada.Containers.Bounded_Synchronized_Queues
      ( Queue_Interfaces => Queue_Interface,
        Default_Capacity => 1);

  Queue_Array : array(1..1) of Data_Queue.Queue;

begin

  Put_Line("Queue_Array(1)'Size = " & Integer'Image(Queue_Array(1)'Size));

end Hello;
```

On the online compiler (GNAT 7.1.1) this triggers: **raised STORAGE_ERROR : s-intman.adb:136 explicit raise**

Intended use is to interface with C-level drivers pulling data from serial port.  (Hence the unchecked_union and other representation clauses)

Have tried wrapping with an Indefinite_Holder assuming the indefinite issue was from the Unconstrained type... and was getting the same error.  Thought that I wouldn't need it because while it's an unconstrained variant it is definite in size.  Same thing either way though.

Also worth noting that:
    test1 : array (ID_Type) Data_Type; -- works
    test2 : Data_Queue.Queue; -- works
    test3 : array (1 .. 2) Data_Queue.Queue; -- Storage_Error

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: After I’ve added the missing `package Whatever is` etc, and fixed up the obvious errors, this compiles OK. If you can’t show the real code, you need to show a cut-down but compilable version that causes the compiler to show the error. (Which compiler release/OS, by the way?)

Comment: You didn't provide a definition for your array element ID_Holder_Queue.Queue.  If that is a typo and you meant Data_Holder_Queue.Queue, the size of just 1 queue shows up as 51539607808 bytes (yes I divided size by 8 and stored it in a Long_Long_Integer to print it).  I would imagine only have a few of those would eat your storage memory, let alone an entire array of them.  You'll probably need to start working backwards to figure out where all that is coming from.  Since you are using "defaults" for your indefinite types, GNAT typically allocates enough storage for all permutations.

Comment: I now know a lot more about synchronized queues, having spent over an hour on this and failing to reproduce your problem. You need to create an [mcve], and you need to tell us what compiler/OS you’re using. Until then, I’m voting to close the question.

Comment: I got interested in this and got something to happen with it on GNAT 7.1.1. It's on an online compiler, but I don't have a real one installed here.  It acts pretty strangely:  http://tpcg.io/KVjTrJ
I don't know the etiquette for adding an MCVE for someone anothers problem.  I didn't want to add it as an answer and comments are limited.  I could edit the OP, but the one I created may not reflect exactly what they are seeing (again as you said, they need to supply an MCVE).

Comment: @Jere: Editing the OP's code beyond formatting is [generally disfavored](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120576/163188), but your [mcve] looks like a useful answer, especially if the result depends on version.  I see several different values of `Data_Holder_Queue.Queue'Size / 8` depending on compiler, e.g. 16#C00000100# and 16#C00000120#,  48 GiB and change.

Comment: `Data_Holder_Queue.Queue` is indefinite (even though it has a `Default_Capacity`), so `’Size` is going to return values corresponding to the range of the constraint (0 .. 2**32 - 1); doesn’t make an actual instance huge, though. Removing the Holder layer removes the problem. Compiler glitch? Still waiting for OP to come back!

Comment: My limited experience checking sizes in GNAT of indefinite types ends up normally being for the size of the constrained version for constrained types and the full size of all permutations for unconstrained types.  The bounded synchronized queue seems to be defined in such a way that GNAT cannot create it in an unconstrained manner.  Bounded objects are not supposed to use pointers, so GNAT has to rely on the define all permutations method.  If I go back and give the Data_Holder_Queue.Queue a constraint, the Storage_Error goes away.

Comment: But it is a limited type, so maybe GNAT should not be trying to do that.

Comment: Many apologies for the incomplete program.  Many thanks to Jere for taking pity and persevering through my poorly structured question and finding the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of the [Bounded_Synchronized_Queue](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-A-18-29.html) is

```ada
 protected type Queue
    (Capacity : Count_Type := Default_Capacity;
     Ceiling  : System.Any_Priority := Default_Ceiling)
       with Priority => Ceiling is
    new Queue_Interfaces.Queue
```

It looks like GNAT is trying to allocate size for all potential permutations of array sizes, leading to an extremely large sized type.  Since this is a limited type, I'm not sure if it still has to do that or not (so may be a bug).

You can fix it by changing the declaration's [discriminant](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-3-7.html) to have a specific [constraint](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-3-7-1.html):

```ada
-- create an array of queues
Queue_Array : array(ID_Type) of ID_Holder_Queue.Queue
    (Capacity => 16,
     Ceiling  => System.Priority'Last);
```

and withing System;

That should remove your storage error.  [This](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.2/gnat_rm/The-Size-of-Discriminated-Records-with-Default-Discriminants.html) might be related if you are using the GNAT compiler.

Comment: Sorry for the delay on getting back.  This seems to have been the crux of my problem.  Appreciate the explanation... and really appreciate you working through my incomplete code.  I'll update the question with a working minimal program that shows the issue (and without the Holder confusing things)  I'll make sure not to make that mistake on future questions!

Comment: Thank you for updating it.  I know it seems like we harp over the MCVE's alot, but it really does reduce the time it takes for us to mess with it.  I had to spend quite a bit of time just trying to get the same error.  Hopefully it doesn't come across as being too picky when we ask

Comment: Nope, not at all; it's completely understandable.  Only excuse I can give for being lazy was that I was convinced given my complete inexperience with Ada that it was a blatant misunderstanding of something that'd jump out.  Won't make that mistake again :)

Comment: @Khanmots You might find the following link interesting since it relates to this issue: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.2/gnat_rm/The-Size-of-Discriminated-Records-with-Default-Discriminants.html
I updated my answer with this link as well.

Comment: The problem occurs when you have an _array_ of queues. A single queue works fine. I wonder whether this is an oversight in the compiler?

Comment: Actually, it's an unconstrained, definite type. Unconstrained means the constraints may be changed (although there's no actual way to do that since the type is limited). Definite means you can declare an object of the type without providing constraints: "V : Data_Queue.Queue;". Limited tagged objects with a default discriminant are allowed in Ada 12 and should be constrained (which is why this works for a Queue variable). That this doesn't work for an array is probably a compiler error.

Comment: Actually, now that I look at the Ada-12 rule for tagged, limited objects with default discriminants, this is a constrained, definite type in Ada 12, but not in earlier versions of Ada.